# Formatação de moedas em PHP

Tags: php

Saudações a todos
Estou a trabalhar num sistema em PHP, e gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que faça com que o PHP reconheça ou use a moeda que está definida no windows!

Comment: No windows? Não seria melhor definida pelo browser?

Comment: Como faria para definir assim

Comment: como assim moeda definida no Windows? Se refere a detectar o país da pessoa e configurar o cambio e o tipo de moeda? Poderia explicar melhor o que precisa para podermos lhe orientar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o seu navegador solicita uma página da Web, ele envia um cabeçalho de aceitação de idioma `ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` que informa quais idiomas você pode aceitar o conteúdo e em que ordem.

Exemplos de strings retornados pelo cabeçalho `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`

- `es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`
- `en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4`

O meu nesta máquina é:

- `pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`

isto quer dizer, eu prefiro o Português do Brasil, se não tiver pode ser Português "geral" (peso 0.8). Na falta destes, posso aceitar inglês dos EUA (q = 0,6), e por último, inglês "geral" (peso 0.4)

O parâmetro `q` (quality factor), indica a ordem de preferência do usuário.

De posse dessa string podemos fazer com que o PHP use a moeda com base nessa informação.

```
/*idioma do navegador do Usuário (o primeiro da lista que tem a mais alta preferencia 
e tem formatação próxima a necessária para uso em setlocale).
entre as aspas simples pode colocar uma default (exemplo: pt-BR ou en-US)
*/
$http_lang = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]) ? substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,5) : '';

//formata para valor válido em setlocale
//substitui o "-" (tracinho) por "_" (underline)
$http_lang = str_replace("-","_",$http_lang);

//Define informações locais
setlocale(LC_ALL, $http_lang);

//retorna dados baseados na localidade corrente definida por setlocale().
$locale_info = localeconv();

//Simbolo da moeda local
$simbolo = $locale_info['currency_symbol'];
//caractere decimal
$decimal_point = $locale_info['decimal_point'];
//Separador de Milhares 
$thousands = $locale_info['thousands_sep'];
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$valor = 12345678900;

echo $simbolo.number_format($valor,2,$decimal_point,$thousands);
```

[**ver resultado no ideone**](https://ideone.com/kXTvWh)

> A maioria dos navegadores tem configurações que permitem verificar ou alterar as configurações de preferência de idioma.